# Loading text file into R to analyze chat log

Tags: r, text, dplyr, grepl, startswith

So, I have been trying to turn a text file (each line is a chat log) into R to turn it into a data frame and further tidy the data.

I am using read.Lines so I can have each log as a single line. Because read.Lines reads them a single long char; I then convert them to strings (I need to parse the log); as per below

```
rawchat <- readLines("disc-W-App-avec-loy.txt")
rawchat <- c(lapply(rawchat, toString))
```

My problem comes when I want to turn this list into data frame:

```
rawchat <- as.data.frame(rawchat)
```

It turns the list into a data frame of 1 observation of 42,000 variables. The intention was to turn it into 42,000 observations of one variable.

Any help please?

By the way, I am pretty new in tidying raw data in R.

---

So, I encountered another block:

I loaded a text file as data frame as per below.

```
rawchat <- readLines("disc-W-App-avec-loy.txt")
rawchat <- as.data.frame(rawchat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(rawchat) <- "chat"
```

I am currently trying to identify any row (42000) that starts with the number 16. I can't seem to apply correctly the `startsWith()` function or the `dplyr` `starts_with()`, even `grepl` with regular expressions.

Could it be the format of the observations of the data frame (`chr`)?

Comment: It looks like `rawchat` is a vector, is that right? If so, maybe `rawchat <- data.frame( text = rawchat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )`?

Comment: Does `data.frame(sapply(rawchat,toString))` give you the right answer, right after you used `readLines`?

Comment: I didn't try that. I did: rawchat <- readLines("disc-W-App-avec-loy.txt")")
rawchat <- as.data.frame(rawchat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `rawchat <- c(lapply(rawchat, toString))`
Just use

```
rawchat <- readLines("disc-W-App-avec-loy.txt")")
rawchat <- as.data.frame(rawchat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Well, I feel a bit ashamed. That was easy. Thanks a lot!